# How are your Quickeys workflows?

Tags: pro-tools, workflow, software, keycommand

Hi

I think that [Quickeys](http://startly.com/) is a great tool to speed up the workflow in Protools: it fill some hole in PT keycommand and some more.

If you use it, how? which are your preferred shortcuts and macros?

Here some of mine:

- A key that zoom at sample level and select pencil; when I release the key, PT zoom out and select smart tool. while the key is pressed i can do my pencil edits with the mouse/tablet
- Another is like shuffle-cut but only for the next region: i can cut a part a bit in the middle of a region, and have the rest of it that snap with the tail of the previous region
- a few are for some tricks with the fades (remove fades, extend the region head and tail and then do fades,  etc)
- Display or not name in regions

These ones come from [Mike Thornton:](http://www.osd-uk.com/)

- move selected region(s) up/down 1/2/3/4/5/6 etc tracks
- open plugins and do some standard stuff (gain +6db, reverse, HP filter, etc) and the close the plugin

(is it possible to attach a file, here? or I can put it in my dropbox)

Answer (score 2):

Hi Davide,

Thanks for the link. Davide knows this, but for other folk I wrote an article on using QuicKeys with Pro Tools back in May 2008 in Sound on Sound [here](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/may08/articles/ptworkshop_0508.htm#top) in which I suggested a number of shortcuts I had developed for Pro Tools as well as using Mac OSX to do shortcuts.

Hope it helps folk,

Mike.

Answer (score 2):

my 3 most used Quikeys:

- display/hide volume graphs
- display/hide pan automation
- display Audiosuite plugins (Gain, Reverse, Pitch etc)

Comment: its interesting that you use a quickey macro for volume graphs considering that the the "-" key will get you there in one keystroke naively (or one doubletap if you're on another automation view)

Comment: I've been using that particular Quickey since a long time before that shortcut was built into ProTools

Answer (score 2):

I use QuicKeys with nearly all the applications I use on a regular basis. For example, when I launch, MarsEdit I have a QuicKeys shortcut that automatically launches other items that I use along with MarsEdit. I also have shortcuts that help me get things done faster in MarsEdit, such as embedding a link with one hot key.

I use QuicKeys to resize and move windows on my dual display. The program also quits  selected applications when they are inactive in the background for a certain amount of time.

QuicKeys is highly essential in my workflow. Here’s my blog where I throw up posts about how I use the program: http://macautomationtips.wordpress.com/

Comment: I found some interesting ideas in your blog. Softkeys is awesone. (I didn't know that function, only the floating toolbar, but I don't like it). just setup a few to open some plugins that I use everytime with different settings. cool!