# Quickening Your Workflow

Tags: workflow, efficiency, shortcut

I'm sure there are many of you who are power users of your particular sets of software, but I would love to hear about additional steps you take to speed up your workflow, whatever your work happens to be.

Do you have custom functions and/or key commands in your software? Do you map your controls to midi controllers or keyboards? Anybody design your own programs or scripts?

For instance, I recently designed a large theatrical sound design in Figure 53's [Qlab](http://figure53.com/qlab/) software. Qlab allows you to program Applescript functionality directly in the program, so I designed several scripts (e.g., automatically creating fade-out cuts, batch changing fade times, etc.) to speed up the process in rehearsal. These scripts were mapped to keystrokes so they were second-nature by week 2.

Please share your strategies, I'm sure there are others out there who would love to snap up ideas.

Cheers,
~Matt

Answer (score 2):

Quickeys and TextExpander are two essential utilities as far as I'm concerned - see the thread on Quickeys below - Quickeys allows scripting of all ui functions, and application switching....

[How are your Quickeys workflows?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/how-are-your-quickeys-workflows)

Comment: I will definitely play with this, I can't believe I missed it somehow. Thanks Tim!

Comment: +1 for Quickeys. I've been doing a lot of audiobook editing over the last few months, and being able to build shortcuts for some of the more repetitive actions (and even some of the lesser-used ones) has saved tons of wear and tear on my hands, plus saved a ton of time.

Unfortunately, they haven't released an upgrade for Mountain Lion yet, as the programmer responsible for the port passed away midway through the work. But they're committed to doing it. If you are on Snow Leopard, though, I really recommend it. I've been using it for only two months and already can't imagine working without.

Answer (score 0):

These might help you out so you don't have to write your own scripts for qlab...
http://wiki.figure53.com/QLab+Scripts+and+Macros

Comment: Definitely! I actually wrote a lot of my scripts based off of the structures provided by these.

If you use Qlab a lot, you should check out http://www.allthatyouhear.com/softwareprojects/ for additional scripting resources. The button bar and script companion are pretty powerful tools.